# Mercurial: how to list merged changeset where the 2nd parent is from a specific branch?

Tags: mercurial

I would like to find all changesets that are a merge from branchX to default.

So first parent of such changeset is on default and second parent of such changeset is on branchX.

Using `hg log -r 'branch("default") & merge()` we have all the merged changeset on default, regardless whether the second parent is branchX or not.

How can I modify the above revset to filter out merged changesets where the 2nd parent is on branchX only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does it in my tests:

```
hg log -r "children(p2(branch(default)) & branch(branchX)) & merge()"
```

Explained:

`p2(branch(default)) & branch(branchX)` gets the changesets on `branchX` that are the second parent of a changeset on the `default` branch.

`children()` gets the children of those changesets

`& merge()` limits those children to those which are merge changesets.  Without this condition you also get the child that is continuing `branchX`

Edit this does it better I think:

```
hg log -r "children(p2(branch(default)) & branch(branchX)) & branch(default)"
```

The first version would include changes on `branchX` that were merges from other branches just after a merge from `branchX` to `default`.